# using CookComputing.XmlRpc read method declaration

Tags: c#, integration, odoo

unable to read employee data . my read method is here that's not working.

protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Login to openerp

```
        IOpenErpLogin rpcClientLogin = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenErpLogin>(); //add  XmlRpcProxyGen.CS File from src folder if required,

        int userid = rpcClientLogin.login("abassc", "sidragill@gmail.com", "admin");
        Label1.Text = userid.ToString();

        IOpenErpAddFields rpcField = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenErpAddFields>();
        object[] filter = new object[1];
        filter[0] = new object[3] { "name", "=", "sisdra" };
        int[] model = rpcField.search("abassc", userid, "admin", "hr.employee", "search", filter);
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(model);
//      int[] search(string dbName, int userId, string dbPwd, string model, string method, object[] filter);

        // IOpenErpAddFields rField = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IOpenErpAddFields>();
            object rd = new object[1];
            rd[0] = new object[2] { "name","work_email" };

           object[] resAdd = rpcField.read("abc", userid, "admin", "hr.employee", "read",model, rd);

        Label3.Text=Convert.ToString(resAdd[0]);     

        //object[] resAdd= rField.get_data("abc", userid,"admin", "hr.employee", "get_data" , rd);
        //Object [] get_data (string dbName, int userId, string pwd, string model, string method, object [] ids);
 // object[] read(string dbName, int userId, string dbPwd, string model, string method, int[] ids, object[] fields);                
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: got thre error messages:                                                                                    Error 5 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'odooLogin.WebForm1.IOpenErpAddFields.read(string, int, string, string, string, int[], object[])' has some invalid arguments
Error 7 Argument 7: cannot convert from 'object' to 'object[]'